# Dockerfile not able to find ionic or cordova after install

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile for which I'm trying to install ionic and cordova. The installation seems to work without error but I'm not able use them inside the container. The thing is, they are installed globally so I not sure what I'm missing. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
FROM openjdk:8

MAINTAINER me

# Install Git and dependencies
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y file git curl zip libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/yarn && \
    mkdir -p /opt/yarn/dist && \
    cd /tmp/yarn && \
    wget -q https://yarnpkg.com/latest.tar.gz && \
    tar zvxf latest.tar.gz && \
    find /tmp/yarn -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -exec mv {} /opt/yarn/dist/ \; && \
    rm -rf /tmp/yarn

RUN ln -sf /opt/yarn/dist/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn && \
    ln -sf /opt/yarn/dist/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg && \
    yarn --version

RUN yarn global add ionic 
RUN yarn global add cordova

# Set up environment variables
ENV ANDROID_HOME="/home/user/android-sdk-linux" \
SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip" \
GRADLE_URL="https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-all.zip"

# Create a non-root user
RUN useradd -m user
USER user
WORKDIR /home/user

# Download Android SDK
RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
&& cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
&& curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
&& unzip sdk.zip \
&& rm sdk.zip \
&& yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

# Install Gradle
RUN wget $GRADLE_URL -O gradle.zip \
&& unzip gradle.zip \
&& mv gradle-4.5.1 gradle \
&& rm gradle.zip \
&& mkdir .gradle

ENV PATH="/home/user/gradle/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}"
```